# Execute select/insert statement within an IF clause Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to execute some statements within the IF clause only if a table exists.
But the issue I am facing is, even when the condition is false, the statements are getting executed.

```
DECLARE
  count_matching_row NUMBER := 0;
  count_matching_tbl NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO count_matching_tbl
  FROM user_tables 
  WHERE LOWER(table_name) = 'tab1';
  IF(count_matching_tbl = 1)
    THEN

      SELECT COUNT (*)
      INTO   count_matching_row
      FROM   test1
      WHERE  ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tab1);

      IF(count_matching_row = 0)
        THEN

          INSERT INTO review_case
            SELECT 
              DISTINCT ID, d,e
            FROM tab1
            WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;

          INSERT INTO review_case_payer
            SELECT 
              a,b,c
            FROM tab1
            WHERE a IS NOT NULL;
         COMMIT;
      END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Whenever I execute these statements, if the table 'tab1' exists it works fine.
If the table tab1 does not exist I get the error

"ORA-06550: line 13, column 14:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"
I get similar errors for each line where I try to access table "tab1"

I tried with ref cursor but still the same, I cannot use it for insert statements.

Comment: If table does not exist, then the code won't compile at all - Oracle will complain that the table doesn't exists. You need to use dynamic SQL instead of static SQL.

Comment: PL/SQL is a compiled language. The whole thing has to compile successfully with valid references or it won't run at all (like Java or Perl). It's not a scripting language that just muddles through line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to the fact that you're using a table that may not exist; this error is thrown because the script has compile problems, not data problems, so the way you try to use the `IF` is not enough to handle your situation.

You need to use some dynamic SQL to handle an object that could not exist; for example, see the following.

If the table does not exist, nothing will be done:

```
SQL> select * from tab1;
select * from tab1
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> declare
  2      vCountTab number;
  3  begin
  4      select count(1)
  5      into vCountTab
  6      from user_tables
  7      where table_name = 'TAB1';
  8
  9      if vCountTab = 1 then
 10          execute immediate 'insert into TAB1 values (1, 2)';
 11      end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If the table exists, the insert will be done:

```
SQL> create table tab1(a number, b number);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2      vCountTab number;
  3  begin
  4      select count(1)
  5      into vCountTab
  6      from user_tables
  7      where table_name = 'TAB1';
  8
  9      if vCountTab = 1 then
 10          execute immediate 'insert into TAB1 values (1, 2)';
 11      end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tab1;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          2

SQL>
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue. If i do not have the table it executes fine but if i have the table i get below error "ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Comment: @Mitali Did you try it exactly as I posted? If you modified it, check the dynamic SQL, you probably have some error there

Comment: yes, but I have two condition. One select inside a if, and then two inserts in another if. I have tried execute immediate with them.

Comment: If you have more than one statement, build a `BEGIN...END;` block; this will work